# At compilation what happen with class template

Tags: c++, templates

what happen when a class template instantiate . i.e i hv a class template  and i have created class for int and class for float, so what will happen at compile time( compiler will create 2 seprate class for int and float) or not?
eg :

```
template <typename T>
class A
{
    public:
        void foo(T t)
        {
            //...
        };
};

int main()
{

   A<int> a; 
    A<float> b;

}
```

Comment: Think about it this way, if the type parameter was for a member of the generated class. How can it be the same class if the layout is different?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, the compiler will create two new classes on-the-fly - one for int and one for float.